PDB restoration on other server
I want to restore only 1 pdb to another server, how can I do that? the rman backup which i have taken from another server has a different control file, and the server on which i am restoring the pdb has a different controlfile.
do I have to restore control file from the backup server? wont that affect the pdbs which already exist on the server where I wnat to restore the pdb
